# How to save LinkedIn Access Token using iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, nsuserdefaults, social-networking

I am using `LinkedIn` in my iOS app. I want to save the access token for the future use.

The token is of non property type which cannot be saved in `NSUserDefaults` directly.
I tried using `NSKeyedArchiver` for this but I got the output:

```
Token===oauth_token "(null)" oauth_token_secret "(null)" oauth_verifier "(null)"
```

The text in the token is coming but the values are coming null.

**Code snippet 1** :

```
-(void)saveData :(LOAToken *)token
{
    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Build the path to the data file
    NSString *dataFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir
                                                                stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"data.archive"]];

    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:
     token toFile:dataFilePath];
}


-(LOAToken *)GetToken
{
    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Build the path to the data file
    NSString *dataFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir
                                                                stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"data.archive"]];

    // Check if the file already exists
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: dataFilePath])
    {
        LOAToken *token;

        token = [NSKeyedUnarchiver
                     unarchiveObjectWithFile: dataFilePath];

        return token;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

I also tried to save like this but the result is same:

```
Token===oauth_token "(null)" oauth_token_secret "(null)" oauth_verifier "(null)"
```

**Code snippet 2** :

```
NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.accessToken];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:@"myEncodedObjectKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSData *myEncodedObject = [defaults objectForKey:@"myEncodedObjectKey"];
            LOAToken *obj = (LOAToken *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: myEncodedObject];
```

Is there anything wrong with my coding or Access Token need some special technique to save?Please Suggest.

Comment: You can save access token directly into user defaults.No need archive it

Comment: Thanks for the response.When I save to defaults directly I get message [NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '<OAToken: 0x1565cf80>' of class 'OAToken'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.

Comment: dont save OAToken object directly save the response body as i did and when you want to use access token initilaize it using reponseBody thi sway and use access token 'self.accessToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKeyPath:@"accessToken"];
[[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:self.accessToken]'

Comment: are u using oAuth 2.0 ?

Comment: OAuth 1.0.Do you have any sample of OAuth 2.0?

Comment: HI Prat, Really is very helpful to me. I am also done all these action  to save access token but i did not get solution. You did very logically. Thanks

Comment: hey @Imran i have migrated to OAuth 2.0 now.

Comment: @arunit21 Thank you :)

Answer (score 10):

this is how I saved. It worked for me.Hope it helps

```
- (void)accessTokenResult:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinish:(NSData *)data
{
    NSDictionary *dict;
    NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    BOOL problem = ([responseBody rangeOfString:@"oauth_problem"].location != NSNotFound);
   if (problem)
   {
        DLog(@"Request access token failed.");
        DLog(@"%@",responseBody);
        dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0",@"success",@"Request access token failed.",@"reason", nil];
   }
   else
   {
       self.accessToken = [[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:responseBody];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:responseBody forKey:@"accessToken"];//save here
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"TokenRefreshDate"];//save here
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
       dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"success",@"Login Successful",@"reason", nil];
   }
   // Notify parent and close this view
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"loginViewDidFinish" object:self userInfo:dict];
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

   }];
 }
```

use saved responseBody in this way

```
self.accessToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKeyPath:@"accessToken"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,maiden-name,picture-url,formatted-name,location,positions,public-profile-url,specialties,num-connections,industry)"];

OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                                   consumer:self.consumer
                                                                      token:[[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:self.accessToken]
                                                                   callback:nil
                                                          signatureProvider:nil];

[request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];
OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
[fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(connectionsApiCallResult:didFinish:)
                  didFailSelector:@selector(connectionsApiCallResult:didFail:) withId:0];
```

I hope I am clear this time

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Next time when we enter the app Will it give access token on calling: self.accessToken = [[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:responseBody]; as we are saving response body(string).

Comment: from next time onwards you should take responseBody string from NSUserDa]efaults and then create OAToken object.responseBody will be stored will be available until you uninstall your app

Comment: Let me clarify as name accessToken Conflicts. `self.accessToken = [[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:responseBody];` in this line accessToken is instance of OAToken and `self.accessToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKeyPath:@"accessToken"];` in this line accessToken is NSString.

Comment: I think I made hurry.I already have the access token then why we are making request OAMutableURLRequest again.

Comment: Do we need to follow all the procedure to get the access token like the first time when login dialog appears and use the access token for the request.Some more hint.

Comment: You dont need to take accessToken by logging in user again as you have the response body.Whatever calls you have to make to api like getting connections list of user.you can do using the responseBody you have stored in user defaults.see my updated answer

Comment: Working like a charm.Thanks a lot.One more question.I have implemented OAuth 1.0. Have you implemented OAuth 2.0.If yes then can you please suggest me the necessary changes that I have to make to in this code.

Comment: I have not implemented it using OAuth 2.0 but you can refer to this link http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication this provides the procedure for migrating from 1.0 to 2.0

Comment: @PratyushaTerli Thanks for your code ,i need to save the user token in parse.com so  do we need to save response body –

Comment: I think you will need access token anyway whether you use parse.com or not and that you can get only by saving the responseBody.

Comment: @SreeHarsha I am sorry but I do not have any idea about parse.com . I am saving responseBody in NSUserDefaults as OAToken object (accessToken) cannot be directly saved into user defaults

Comment: When I go on with the above code I get the below error, does anyone have any idea? Please let me know. auth_problem=signature_invalid&oauth_problem_advice=com.linkedin.security.auth.pub.LoginDeniedInvalidAuthTokenException

Comment: Hello @PratyushaTerli, How can I clear cache for LinkedIn like we clear for twitter and Facebook ?

Comment: You can clear accessToken saved in user defaults to clear cache.